# How to define aliases in npm/npx?

Tags: windows, powershell, npm

Because of some windows restrictions every time I want to remove node_modules folder I have to use `npx rimraf node_modules`.
I was wondering if there was some way to define an alias for this command?

ex: `npx deletenode`

Small update

I found a temporary solution - for now I defined a powershell alias for this command. I followed [this tutorial](https://graficos.net/blog/2019-10-28-how-to-set-aliases-in-powershell) and added this code to `Profiles.ps1`

```
function delnode { npx rimraf node_modules }
```

Second edit: this works as well with no need to install rimraf module:

```
function npmclr { echo node_modules package-lock.json |rm -r }
```

3rd edit: this will recursively remove all node_modules folders inside current directory and log removed folders:

```
function npmclrall { 
  Get-ChildItem -Include node_modules -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | Foreach-Object { `
  Write-Host ($_.Message -replace'(.*)Target "(.*)"(.*)','Removing File $2') -ForegroundColor Yellow 
  }
} # recursive clean up npm packages and log
```

Comment: I don't think this is possilbe because npx and deletenode would be considered two separate commands by your terminal session. npx is already parsed as the identifier of node package manager and npx kicks in and starts looking for cmdline options. I think the solution you came up with is the best way to go. There are also ways to define aliases outside of powershell if you want to also use the aliases inside of non-powershell terminal sessions.

Comment: Can you link to such a solution?, not sure what to google for.

Comment: You'll have to @-mention Efie for them to be notified. One option is to create a batch file (`.cmd`) placed in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`, which both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell can then invoke by name only.